# Multiple Query Inside While Loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I try to run multiple queries inside while loop, and nothing happens, not showing error and not showing success. anyone can explain or help me solve this?
here's my code

```
<?php

include('config.php');
    
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM inventory_masuk_dummy';
$query  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        
        $jumlah = $row['jml'];
        $size = $row['size'];
        $nama_barang = $row['nama_barang'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        
        $sql2 = "UPDATE inventory_dummy SET jumlah = jumlah+$jumlah WHERE nama_barang = '$nama_barang' AND size = '$size'";
        
        $sql3 = "UPDATE inventory_masuk_dummy SET status = '2' WHERE status='1'";
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2) && $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3)) {
    echo "Berhasil di ubah, anda akan segera dialihkan";
    }
}      
        
echo "Nothing...";
        
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion sir, I'll make it to PDO version.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is your code does not execute the `$sql2` and `$sql3`, you can execute it again with `mysqli_query`

```
<?php

include('config.php');
    
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM inventory_masuk_dummy';
$query  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        
        $jumlah = $row['jml'];
        $size = $row['size'];
        $nama_barang = $row['nama_barang'];
        $status = $row['status'];
        
        $sql2 = "UPDATE inventory_dummy SET jumlah = jumlah+$jumlah WHERE nama_barang = '$nama_barang' AND size = '$size'";
        
        $sql3 = "UPDATE inventory_masuk_dummy SET status = '2' WHERE status='1'";

        if ( mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) && mysqli_query($conn, $sql3) ) {
             echo "Berhasil di ubah, anda akan segera dialihkan";
        }

}      


echo "Nothing...";
```

Comment: ohh okay, i will try add these, how about this 
`...
$query2  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        $query3  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2) && $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3))
...`

Comment: there is no need for fetching `UPDATE` query